# How did Naruto land the finishing Rasengan on Pain?

Tags: naruto

I watched Naruto's fight with Pain the other day, and I don't quite understand how Naruto managed to land a Rasengan on the Deva Path in that sequence of attacks which started with 2 Rasenshurikens.

This is what I have understood so far: Pain deflected first shuriken, then he jumped to dodge the second one flying towards his blind spot. As he landed, he was attacked by numerous Naruto clones, who were camouflaging as rocks with Henge no Jutsu (Transformation Technique), and he deflected all of them with Shinra Tensei yet again. After that, I completely lost track of what was going on and how he managed to land that Rasengan eventually.

Can anyone explain what happened with respect to the five-second interval and how Naruto managed to beat Pain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happened is as follows:

- Naruto throws first shuriken, Shinra Tensei deflects it.
- Naruto throws second shuriken, Pain dodged.
- Naruto's Multiple Shadow Clone Technique attempts to attack Pain with all the clones, Shinra Tensei deflects them all.
- Naruto, taking advantage of the 5 seconds it takes him to recharge, flings himself with the aid of 2 clones, and lands the Rasengan straight at him before he can use Shinra Tensei again.

Still not clear? Tell me in the comments :)

Comment: +1 and for the last line in the answer in the anime its shown all the clones stand together to brace the attack right? and on top of that he has to create a rasengan and jump to hit him. that seems a lot of time for 5 secs.

Comment: Basically, all the clones try to mob Pain. Pain then uses Shinra Tensei and Naruto realizes that he can use all his clones to withstand it and not take the full force of the Shinra Tensei. After that, the Shinra Tensei has a 5 second cooldown, but Naruto didn't get pushed back far because of his clones. Naruto closes the distance with a Rasengan in 5 seconds.

Comment: krikara. makes more sense now. thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

After coming out of Pain's Chibaku Tensei, Naruto first snatched a chakra receiver from the Deva Path, and stabbed himself momentarily to track down Nagato's location using his Sage Mode.

He then created two shadow clones and then a Rasenshuriken using these clones. He also used two smoke bombs for deception. He had already used this trick previously during the battle, when he had first sent a real Rasenshuriken and then his real self disguised as a Rasenshuriken.

Pain began anticipating the same thing to happen. As expected, Naruto sent the first real Rasenshuriken, which pain promptly deflected using Shinra Tensei. However, this time, the second Rasenshuriken was a real one, hidden under the first one as a shadow shuriken. Naruto's two shadow clones also emerged, but Pain was prepared having already seen this trick before (or so he thought). He stabbed the two clones with his chakra receivers, and also dodged the Rasenshuriken.

The purpose of this part of Naruto's plan was to force Pain to use Shinra Tensei, to take advantage of the five second interval during the next part of his plan. It is now revealed that Naruto had previously used the Mass Shadow Clone technique, and then transformed those multiple clones into boulders. Naruto undoes the transformation, aiming to attack Pain with these shadow clones.

However, this doesn't work as expected since Pain's ability returns at the last moment, and he uses the Shinra Tensei to push away Naruto's shadow clones before he can land a direct hit on Pain.

Now Naruto switches to a backup plan, wherein he uses the mass shadow clones as a support for the main body to oppose Shinra Tensei's push. Having used the Shinra Tensei, Pain's five second interval kicks in *again*, during which Naruto finally lands a direct hit on Pain using his Rasengan. Having defeated the Deva Path, he proceeds to meet the original Nagato.

Comment: Wow, turns out Madara already wrote an answer while I was busy writing mine!

Comment: Madara is an Uchiha, of course he has natural speed than you,, lols..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Naruto is in Sage Mode. When you are in Sage Mode which taught and learned by the toads, the advantages afforded include:

- The user's physical strength, **speed**, stamina, **reflexes**, **perception**
  and durability dramatically increase.
- The user's ninjutsu, genjutsu, and taijutsu become more powerful.
- The user can harness the natural energy surrounding them, turning it
  into an extension of their body, which increases the reach of their
  attacks.
- The user gains the ability to sense Chakra around them.

As I emphasized the speed and reflexes, Naruto can react in a split seconds and took advantage the 5 secs interval and make it work.

Comment: well your answer is telling me what sage mode does. actually before he lands a hit on pain naruto completely loses his sage chakra after the 2nd rasen shuriken.

Comment: Actually, Naruto wasn't in sage mode when the final Rasengan hit.